# Error is an undefined subroutine

Tags: genexus

error src0304: ''ManageError'' is an undefined subroutine. Me sale este error al momento que pongo el codigo para enviar un email en Genexus alguien que me pueda ayudar como corregirlo porfavor

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente estes poniendo el código que se te indicó en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/541898/291538).

En ese ejemplo no está escrita la subrutina que atiende los errores. Para agregarla debes poner al final del código del procedimiento que estés escribiendo:

```
Sub 'ManageError'
  // Aqui va tu codigo
EndSub
```